# Brownian motion process and brownian bridge process

Tags: statistics

Let $U$ be a brownian bridge process , and let $B (t) = (1+t) U \left(\dfrac{t}{1+t}\right)$ , $t\geq 0,$ show that $B$ is a brownian motion on $t\geq 0$?

Comment: I suppose z=t/(t+1)) , but not sure

Comment: I find it difficult to find covariance

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $s<t$ and note that $\frac{s}{1+s} < \frac{t}{1+t}$. Then:

$Cov(B_s,B_t) = cov\left((1+s)X(\frac{s}{1+s}), (1+t)X(\frac{t}{1+t})  \right) = (1+s)(1+t)Cov(X(\frac{s}{1+s}), X(\frac{t}{1+t}))$

The brownian bridge has covariance $s-st$ for $s<t$.

So $Cov(B_s,B_t) = (1+s)(1+t)(\frac{s}{1+s}-\frac{s}{1+s}\frac{t}{1+t}) = s$